# How to send a type(table) as a parameter in oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE amp_CheckVideos
(
  v_json IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_Ids IN TVP_AMP_METADATA,
  v_tags IN TVP_AMP_METADATA,
  v_newVideos IN TVP_AMP_VIDEOS
) is 
begin
```

I have TVP_AMP_METADATA and TVP_AMP_VIDEOS as types in my database. 
Couldn't seem to find those types while creating the procedure.

Comment: Nothing looks inherently wrong. Could you share the exact error you get?

Comment: Could you include the definitions of each type? It's unclear from your question what exactly they are.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say you have them but you can't find them. By the way, normally the `v_` prefix is used for variables.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in passing custom Database types as "variable" types in pl/sql. It depends on the calling user and if it has the required permissions (grants) to use them. The simplest thing to do it to create an anonymous block like `declare l_tvp_meta tvp_amp_metadata; begin null; end` and try to execute it. If the user/schema doesn't have permissions it will output the same error message. Provide sample definition of those two types, as well as select from ALL_TAB_PRIVS, USER_TAB_PRIVS or DBA_TAB_PRIVS for the pair user/object you're running this procedure with.

Comment: I have the select in the stored procedure and if I execute it in a separate window, I get the following error
ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here while I am selecting from one of the type.
the query is following.
select FileId into v_cnt from v_newVideos